# Equation Wrapping

Tags: equations

I have a long equation and I am trying to wrap it. Here is the code I am using.

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{aligned}
0 = A f_d V_d C_x^d - A f_d V_d C_{x+\Delta x}^d \\
+ A \Delta k_m(C^b-C^d) 
+A\left(-D_e\frac{dC^d}{dx}\right)_x - A\left(-D_e\frac{dC^d}{dx}\right)_{x+\Delta x} \\
+ A\Delta\rho_c(1-f_b)(1-\varepsilon_d)R_A
\end{aligned}
\end{eqnarray}
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

I would like to move equation to left

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from.

Comment: you have used the `align` environment for multiple lines, but i don't see any `&` indicating alignment points.  (`&` is ordinarily placed before signs of relation, and, with a `\quad` space following the `&`, before signs of operation.)  since the second line is very long, it may just exceed the specified page width; in that case, breaking the second line earlier is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never use `eqnarray`, see [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196). Here the solution seems to be `multline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
0 = A f_d V_d C_x^d - A f_d V_d C_{x+\Delta x}^d \\
+ A \,\Delta k_m(C^b-C^d)
+A\left(-D_e\frac{dC^d}{dx}\right)_{\!x} - A\left(-D_e\frac{dC^d}{dx}\right)_{\!x+\Delta x} \\
+ A\,\Delta\rho_c(1-f_b)(1-\varepsilon_d)R_A
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

I've made a couple of manual adjustments: `\!` in front of the subscripts following `\right)`, so they are placed nearer the bottom of the parenthesis; I also added `\,` in front of `\Delta` when it follows a factor, in order to make clearer it is not a multiplier, but an operator.

[image]

You may want to define a command for this, so `\Delta` as an operator is distinguished from the letter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\opDelta}{\mathop{}\!\Delta}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
0 = A f_d V_d C_x^d - A f_d V_d C_{x+\opDelta x}^d \\
+ A \opDelta k_m(C^b-C^d)
+A\left(-D_e\frac{dC^d}{dx}\right)_{\!x} - A\left(-D_e\frac{dC^d}{dx}\right)_{\!x+\opDelta x} \\
+ A\opDelta\rho_c(1-f_b)(1-\varepsilon_d)R_A
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

A similar treatment should be used for the “differential d”:

```
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}
```

Finally your image suggests the formula before “reads” is typed in as

```
$x$+$\Delta x$
```

which is wrong and should be

```
$x+\Delta x$
```

or, with the new command

```
$x+\opDelta x$
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless your textblock is unusually narrow, I can't see a (good) reason for using more than two lines to typeset the equation.

I suggest using a `split` environment inside an `equation` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'split' environment
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
0 &= A f^{}_d V^{}_d C_x^d 
   - A f^{}_d V^{}_d C_{x+\Delta x}^d 
   + A \Delta k_m(C^b-C^d) \\
&\quad + A\Bigl(\!-D_e\frac{dC^d}{dx}\Bigr)_{\!x} 
       - A\Bigl(\!-D_e\frac{dC^d}{dx}\Bigr)_{\!x+\Delta x} 
       + A\Delta\rho_c(1-f_b)(1-\varepsilon_d)R_A
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```